# Assigning an object to another variable

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and noticed when a variable is assigned to another variable, it does not copy the contents of it, rather becomes the extension of same variable. For example:

```
var data1 = {"name": "john", "age": 34, "city": "london"}

var data2 = data1

delete data2.city

console.log(data1)
{"name": "john", "age": 34}
```

The above code will not only delete the `city` property from `data2` but also from `data1`.

How should I only COPY the contents into `data2` from `data1` and change it without disturbing the `data1`?

Comment: FYI you're not 'inheriting', you're assigning.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables point to the same object.

```
var data2 = Object.assign({}, data1)
```